# mvvm solving nested models and viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to understand when to use models, when viewmodels and so on. Especially with nested lists. So my viewmodels handles events and commands and modify the model in basic... So in my basic examples it looks mostly like the viewmodel has a reference to the model and delegates propertys.

```
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _model.Name; }
            set
            {
                _model.Name = value.Trim();
                RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
```

But what happens now if I have a list of models which has a list of models too.
Example: Users which have a list of todos. So what can I do now? My first thought is to create `UserViewModel` & `TodoViewModel`. So I have an `ObservableCollection<UserViewModel>` and every `UserViewModel` has a `ObservableCollection<TodoViewModel>`.

And everytime I add a Todo I create `Todo` and `TodoViewModel` bind the todo object to the `TodoViewModel` and so on? This sounds like a big overload of objects...

Am I to strict? Why do I need ViewModels here? What do I miss here? Why not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` into the models? And Eventhandling and Commands are different files and I can bind the parameter to them. So the models dont know about the views and the views dont need viewmodels?

Answer (score 1):

ViewModels are only for the view. It acts as a glue code between the model and view.

**What does this mean? **

Take for example you have a `UserList` page or form (view). You would then have a `UserListViewModel` which holds all the DTOs (Data Transfer Object). You should not directly expose these DTOs as properties but as fields with properties that follows the `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation for data binding. Within your view model you can expose commands (delegates) to your view to perform actions such as http requests, data processing, I/O, etc. but for any changes to the DTOs you should properly notify the view so that the view is aware of what happened if they need to know.

Do not apply the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to each and every model or DTO inside your view model as it is just another overhead as you've said.

A more OCD version of the MVVM pattern is the MVPVM (Model-View-Presenter-View Model) where commands and data manipulations are done within the Presenter and not on the View Model which leaves the View Model strictly as a model for data binding.

Comment: But with the ur `UserList` and `UserListViewModel` aproach I would have two objects for "1" thing. If I would only has a `UserList` Model which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and bind the properties to the View and as an example a user add would be a `UserAddCommand.cs` which I can bind to the view too. Code would be seperate. 

Maybe the MVPVM fits more into my way of thinking.

Comment: No, I meant UserList as your view. that's your XAML file in WPF

Comment: Ok thanks. So there is no "real" Model (the way people learn this in school). The ViewModel holds the Property like `Name`, `Color`, `Size` and the DTO's could be a service class like `TodoSaveService` ?

Comment: Yes, model in MVVM is broad if you literally stick to the Model-View-View Model concept. You can have a POCO (Plain Old CLR Object)  such as `User` which contains user properties but you should not directly bind to those from your view, instead expose a View Model property that access the `User` property so that you are sure that `INotifyPropertyChanged` is applied. `TodoSaveService` chould be called within your `UserAddCommand`. Not sure why you added `.cs` but as far as I can remember commands are exposed as View Model properties.

Comment: On side note, you should check [What is the Difference Between a DTO and a POCO?](http://www.referencebits.com/2009/03/what-is-difference-between-dto-and-poco.html?showComment=1438933066640) as those terms are widely used in .NET programming. Also look into [Design Patterns by Tutorials: MVVM](https://www.raywenderlich.com/34-design-patterns-by-tutorials-mvvm) Sometimes we get confused because we don't know the definition of the terms even though they are simple concepts

Comment: the `.cs` because I could reuse it in different ViewModels. Thank you. The POCO thing seems to much and overloading. It would be like my example above with User, UserViewModel, Todo and TodoViewModel

Answer (score 1):

If you strictly follow the concept of MVVM, then your implementation of the property that connects the value with the Model is not true.
This implementation assumes for the ViewModel “knowledge” about the internal structure and functioning of the Model.
And ViewModel should not have such knowledge.

In the "strict" implementation of MVVM, the Model has no properties.
She has only methods and events.
ViewModel calls the public method and passes the desired value to it.
Will the state of the model be changed after that - ViewModel does not know.
If the state has changed, then the Model raises an event.
Upon receiving this event, the ViewModel reads the necessary data and updates its properties, which are used for bindings in the View.

Demo-code:

**Model**

```
public delegate void NameChangedHandler(object sender, string newName);
public class ModelName
{

    public event NameChangedHandler NameChangedEvent;

    private string name;
    public void SendName(string name)
    {
        // Some business logic to handle the accepted value.
        // You can transfer to the server, change other values ​​and the like.
        // In this example is simply stored in a private field.
        name = name.Trim();
        if (this.name != name)
        {
            this.name = name;
            NameChangedEvent?.Invoke(this, this.name);
        }
    }
}
```

**Basic implementation of INPC**

```
/// <summary>Base class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged.</summary>
public abstract class BaseINPC : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>Called AFTER the property value changes.</summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the property.
    /// In the property setter, the parameter is not specified. </param>
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

    /// <summary> A virtual method that defines changes in the value field of a property value. </summary>
    /// <typeparam name = "T"> Type of property value. </typeparam>
    /// <param name = "oldValue"> Reference to the field with the old value. </param>
    /// <param name = "newValue"> New value. </param>
    /// <param name = "propertyName"> The name of the property. If <see cref = "string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (string)" />,
    /// then ArgumentNullException. </param> 
    /// <remarks> If the base method is not called in the derived class,
    /// then the value will not change.</remarks>
    protected virtual void Set<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(propertyName));

        if ((oldValue == null && newValue != null) || (oldValue != null && !oldValue.Equals(newValue)))
            OnValueChange(ref oldValue, newValue, propertyName);
    }

    /// <summary> A virtual method that changes the value of a property. </summary>
    /// <typeparam name = "T"> Type of property value. </typeparam>
    /// <param name = "oldValue"> Reference to the property value field. </param>
    /// <param name = "newValue"> New value. </param>
    /// <param name = "propertyName"> The name of the property. </param>
    /// <remarks> If the base method is not called in the derived class,
    /// then the value will not change.</remarks>
    protected virtual void OnValueChange<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, string propertyName)
    {
        oldValue = newValue;
        RaisePropertyChanged(propertyName);
    }

}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModelName : BaseINPC
{
    private ModelName model = new ModelName();
    public ViewModelName()
        => model.NameChangedEvent += NameChangedMethod;

    private void NameChangedMethod(object sender, string newName) 
        => Name = newName;

    private string _name;
    public string Name { get => _name; set => Set(ref _name, value); }

    protected override void OnValueChange<T>(ref T oldValue, T newValue, string propertyName)
    {
        base.OnValueChange(ref oldValue, newValue, propertyName);

        if (propertyName == nameof(Name))
            model.SendName(Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: im confused. It looks like a circle call, View calls `ViewModelName.Name = "NewName"` -> `Set()` -> `OnValueChange()` -> `model.SendName()` -> `NameChangedEvent.Invoke()` -> `NameChangedMethod()` -> `Name = "NewName` -> `Set()`. Or do I miss something?

Comment: Comparisons of the new and old meanings are everywhere: in the Model and in the ViewModel.
If the values ​​are not changed, no further call is made.
Using assignment checking is a typical implementation in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the best way, but I create special view model for model if it needs some special logic for work with it. If it has no special logic, or work with it takes pair lines of code I do all work in high level view model, like Users in your case. Then if it becomes big I refactor it, and move code to nested view model.